# Basic structure/syntax/method help. Class for basic quiz

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I am new to Java and need help understanding a few things. This is my code for a class designed to return a number of marks in a quiz.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
/**Contains methods to create an ArrayList of possible answers ask a question and mark it accordingly
 * @author Ben Fowler
 * @version
 */

public class ExamQuestionNumerical extends ExamQuestion{


public ExamQuestionNumerical(String question, int maximalMark, int correctAnswer) {
    super(question, maximalMark);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ExamQuestionNumerical q1 = new ExamQuestionNumerical("10 - 6 = ?", 3, 1);

private int addAnswer(){
    /**Adds 3 possible answers to the ArrayList
     * @returns void
     */
    answer.add(3);
    answer.add(4);
    answer.add(5);
}

private int returnMarks(correctAnswer){
    /**
     * @returns either max marks for a correct answer or 0 for incorrect.
     */
    if (q1.answer = 1){
        return maximalMark;
    }else {return 0;}
}
```

Now, obviously the problem is with the bottom method, I just need to return a mark for the question. I (think I) have stored 3 possible answers in the ArrayList and need a method to return a score based on whether the right answer is chosen. I know I am missing basic knowledge of structure/syntax/more but please help, I can spend hours of research going in circles or with a little guidance, actually get somewhere. Thanks

Comment: Could you include a main method that runs this class, as well as desired and actual outputs. And probably ExamQuestion too. If it were possible to cut this down into a small self contained example that would be excellent

Comment: `if (q1.answer = 1)` This part is what we're looking at, yes? From what I can tell, answer is an ArrayList (and setting it equal to 1 is not going to run). You have a list of answers, and the correct answer (which may be an index or an int). What your "target" is should be evaluating whether or not `correctAnswer` coincides with q1 answer. You also need an input/field that stores a student's response.

Comment: A few notes: 1. In the constructor you pass correctAnswer but don't do anything with it? Surely you should store this somewhere. 2. addAnswer should return an int. What was your desired functionality of this method? 3. returnMarks(correctAnswer) has invalid syntax, you must specify the type of the argument. 4. (q1.answer = 1) is invalid -> In Java the comparison operator is '=='. Also you are comparing an int to a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. Here is a list containing several of them:

1. Your `addAnswer()` method should return `void` not `int`, because it's not currently returning anything.
2. You need to provide a type for the `correctAnswer` argument to the `returnMarks` method. I'm guessing `int` might be appropriate.
3. The statement `if (q1.answer = 1)` should be `if (q1.answer == 1)`, note the double equals sign which is used for comparison. Single equals signs are used for assignment.
4. You are creating an instance of `ExamQuestionNumerical` within your class (named `q1`). This seems very odd. This is causing errors because you don't call `addAnswer()` on it, yet  you refer to it in the `returnMarks` method. I would suggest you don't need to create an instance within the class - create the instance within a `main()` method in a test class somewhere.
5. You should really mark your fields as `private` in your class. In this case, `answer` should probably be private. Convention dictates that field definitions come first in your class, above your constructor.

Make sure you are using an IDE, such as Eclipse, to write your code. This ensures many of the problems will be detected automatically thanks to the continuous background compiling.

Comment: Thanks, I have noted all these things and amended accordingly. I am still having problems but answer was very helpful and I am lots closer cheers.